# Prove $\frac{1}{z^2}=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(n+1)(z-1)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove that for any complex number $z$ such that $|z-1|<1$, one has:
>
> $\frac{1}{z^2}=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(n+1)(z-1)^n$

What I've done;

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{z^2}=\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{1-(1-z)}\right)^2=\left(\sum\limits_{k\ge0}(1-z)^k\right)^2=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\sum\limits_{i+j=k}(1-z)^i(1-z)^j$

$\displaystyle=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\sum\limits_{i+j=k}(-1)^k(z-1)^i(z-1)^j$

but is the number of cases $i+j=k$ not always even ? and are my steps correct ?

Of course you can also give another hint.

Comment: This question plus your name make quite an ironic duo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First replace $i+j=k$ by $i+j=n$, the first steps are correct but there is no need for the final step you can stop at :
$$\cdots=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\sum\limits_{i+j=n}(1-z)^i(1-z)^j$$
and this can be simplified to:
$$\cdots=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\sum\limits_{i+j=n}(1-z)^n$$
and you have just to continue: the number of elements (i,j) such that $i+j=n$ is $n+1$ and to finish you have :
$$\cdots=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\sum\limits_{i+j=n}(1-z)^n=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}(1-z)^n\sum\limits_{i+j=n}1=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}(n+1)(1-z)^n$$

and here you deduce your final result

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(n+1)(z-1)^n=(\sum\limits_{n \ge1}(1-z)^n)'$

Comment: As I see it, this doesn't answer the question the OP is asking. However it answers the question that I think the OP really wants to ask. If this is the case, I appeal to you, @derivative, to adjust your question so I can up vote this answer.

Comment: @GitGud You are right, this is not really the answer to the OP. I however felt it was the best to advance in the right direction.

Comment: @Martigan Thanks this method seems better but is the sign on the RHS correct ?

Comment: @derivative Perhaps not, I have to admit I may have been a bit too quick on the sign...

Comment: @Martigan I mean $\frac1z=\sum_{n\ge0}(1-z)^n$ and $\left(\frac1z\right)'=-\frac{1}{z^2}$ should imply that $\frac{1}{z^2}=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(n+1)(z-1)^n$$=-\left(\sum_{n\ge0}(1-z)^n\right)'=-\left(\sum_{n\ge1}(1-z)^n\right)'$, or am I wrong ?